# Пайчарм не видит пайтон, то есть не находит его(

Tags: python, pycharm

Пайчарм не может увидеть пайтон, из-за того, что я удалил случайно файл с модулями (

```
Process finished with exit code 9009
```

выдает вот это...

Comment: Переустановите питон

Comment: Проверьте работоспособность через консоль ОС, дальше будет понятно это проблема с питоном или косяк в PyCharm

Comment: что значит не видит - не видит интерпретатор? ну так создайте новый `venv` и укажите путь